# Add multiple background in data set attributes and animate them Using CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to load multiples background images in data set attributes and animate it. Is it possible? Currently, I have load only one image.

```js
'use strict';

(function($) {
  $('.set-bg').each(function() {
    var bg = $(this).data('setbg');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="blog-item set-bg extraImg" data-setbg="https://dummyimage.com/300">
        <h4>Travel</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How you want to set multiple image? means there are 5 `h4` tags, you need to set 5 images url? or what you want, you need to animate image, what is your exact question?

Comment: @turivishal: I want to add only two images. in <div class="blog-item set-bg extraImg" data-setbg="https://dummyimage.com/300">

Comment: okay how you will put this image name in your tag, its static or dynamic? because if you need to set in single field `data-setbg` then you have to define urls as comma separated like `data-setbg="url1,url2"`

Comment: @turivishal for now it will be static

Comment: I have added a answer, hope his help.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, have added comma separated 2 urls in `data-setbg` attribute, for more clarity i added fix height of `set-bg` class.

```js
'use strict';

(function($) {
  $('.set-bg').each(function() {
    var bgImgs = [];
    var bg = $(this).data('setbg').split(",");
    bg.forEach((value)=>{
        bgImgs.push("url("+ value +")");
    });
    $(this).css('background-image', bgImgs.join(","));
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.set-bg{
    height: 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="blog-item set-bg extraImg" data-setbg="https://dummyimage.com/300,https://dummyimage.com/600">
        <h4>Travel</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.